# Docker container - Send log from a process other than main (PID1)

Tags: linux, bash, docker, logging, stdout

I can see all `STDOUT`s and `STDERR`s came from `my-container`'s main/initial process (`PID1`) are sent to `docker logs my-container` and the same is valid for any application that is run in this process.

For example, when I `docker attach` to my container, `echo` and also other commands' outputs are sent to logs, but when I'm in a process other than the main, e.g when I run `docker exec`, no any outputs are sent to logs. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirect the output to `/proc/1/fd/1` to get it into the logs.

As an example, start a container with

```
docker run -d --name mycontainer debian tail -f /dev/null
```

then put the contents of `/etc/os-release` into the logs with

```
docker exec mycontainer sh -c 'cat /etc/os-release > /proc/1/fd/1'
```

Note that you have to have the redirection in single quotes. If you don't, it'll be handled by the shell on the host. By using quotes, it's handled by the shell inside the container which is what you want.

`docker logs mycontainer` will now show the contents of the file.

So basically write whatever you want to `/proc/1/fd/1` and it'll show up in the log.